# Kivy importing Python variables into inline KV

Tags: python, variables, kivy

I've been banging my head off this particular wall for days now. None of the relevant articles here have worked, so I really need to know where I'm going wrong. The relevant sections of code are:

```
    def print_scb(myscb):
        print(myscb)
        scb_string = ''
        scb_list = [ 'Combat' , 'Communication' , 'Manipulation' , 'Mental' , 'Perception', 'Physical' ]
        for s in scb_list:
            zz = str(myscb[s])
            scb_string = scb_string + s + " " + zz + "% "
        return scb_string
```

And the inline KV section is:

```
<CharacterSheet>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text:'Stats'
        Label:
            text: app.print_stats()
        Label:
            text:'Rolls'
        Label:
            text: app.print_rolls()
        Label:
            text:'SCM'
        Label:
            text: app.print_scm()
        Label:
            text:'SCB'
        Label:
            text: app.print_scb()
        Button:
            text:'Quit'
            on_press: sys.exit()
        Button:
            text:'Back to Start'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'welcome'
```

""")

The program crashes with:

```
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 114:
 ...
     112:            text:'SCB'
     113:        Label:
 >>  114:            text: app.print_scb()
     115:        Button:
     116:            text:'Quit'
  ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 114:
 ...
     112:            text:'SCB'
     113:        Label:
 >>  114:            text: app.print_scb()
     115:        Button:
     116:            text:'Quit'
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1742, in   create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "<string>", line 114, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 935, in __getattribute__
 object.__getattribute__(self, '_ensure_app')()
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 930, in _ensure_app
     app.bind(on_stop=lambda instance:

   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2115, in _apply_rule
     rctx['ids'])
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1747, in create_handler
 cause=tb)
```

The whole code has been posted to dpaste at [BrpGui.py](http://dpaste.com/1PRJ07W)

The print_scb() functions returns a string.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?
Colin

Comment: is print_scb a global function?

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN . print_scb is not a global function. It is defined in the `CharacterSheet(Screen):` class. Does it need to be moved to a different area of the script?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments.

> print_scb is not a global function. It is defined in the CharacterSheet(Screen): class.

When you defined the function you forgor self.

So instead of `def print_scb(myscb):` it shall be `def print_scb(self, myscb):`

Also in your kv file, dont use `app.print_scb()` but `root.print_scb()`
Since it belongs to that class.

But since your function wants a parameter, it will throw an error. So you need to call it with a parameter. like this `root.print_scb(some_variable)`

From the docs https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html -

> There are three keywords specific to Kv language:
>
> app: always refers to the instance of your application.
>    root: refers to the base widget/template in the current rule
>    self: always refer to the current widget

Comment: Now it errors with ` ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 114:
 ...
     112:            text:'SCB'
     113:        Label:
 >>  114:            text: root.print_scb()
     115:        Button:
     116:            text:'Quit'
 ...
 TypeError: print_scb() missing 1 required positional argument: 'myscb'
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1742, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "<string>", line 114, in <module>`
 
 I had to omit some of the errors but I think the important one is there.

Comment: @ColinBrett oh you still didnt get that it takes a parameter. :) answer updated

Comment: If I change the call to print_scb from text: root.print_scb() to text: root.print_scb(myscb) it errors with "NameError: name 'myscb' is not defined" Colin

Comment: @ColinBrett what is myscb. Python asks the same you know. You did not tell anyone

Comment: @ColinBrett Can you add the important errors from the comments to your question? That way they are more readable and others with similar problems can see all information without digging into the comments.

Comment: @syntonym agreed. But this seems more like a "plz debug my code" in which case, all his code is the relevant section, because he lacks some basic understanding of how python and kivy works. He had a similar question yesterday, where one problem solved released a bunch of other errors.

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN . Calls within calls, I'm afraid. I've posted an explanation to http://dpaste.com/3SEEHTM .

Comment: @ColinBrett it would be alot easier to just paste the whole code. Then I can see whats going on. and the whole kv file

Comment: @ColinBrett also then I could test it. And fix your errors. And then tell you what is wrong. If you want that

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN , @ syntonym ... noobies gotta noob :( Sorry for wasting your time on this. If you can still help, the entire code was posted to dpaste at [link]http://dpaste.com/1PRJ07W Colin

Comment: @ColinBrett I did not mean to be rude. I will happyly help you. What I meant, is this is not a single question :) you know. Because it releases a series of errors each time I answer the Question you asked.

Comment: @ColinBrett what is the module brp_stats and dice_roller?

Comment: @ColinBrett on line 153 you are callin human() inside of human(). What do you want to achieve here. The same happens for all the other races. http://dpaste.com/0KX2BEN Also could I get your email or something. Or do you use irc chat. This is not suitable for what we are doing :)

Comment: @ColinBrett also this is what I did so far http://dpaste.com/3CXKT43 I just commented out those imports. This fixed the CharacterSheet class

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN . Thanks for your offer. I have fixed human() calling human() by changing the name in brp_stats.py to human_stats() (etc for the other races). My email is colinabrett AT gmail.com if you can drop me a line. Colin

Comment: You should also be able to use the stackoverflow chat. Sometimes it does get triggered by discussion in the comments but apparently it did not here.  [This one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117611/38432104-kivy-importing-python-variables-into-inline-kv) should work.

Comment: Okay, it looks like one cannot grant a user the right to talk if (s)he has a too low reputation.. stupid chat. Sorry.

Comment: @syntonym :D yea tought of that. Well he needs 20 reputation

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN There is even a button "invite users" which is labeled that  users who do not have enough reputation can then speak. But.. it does not. Confusing. Nevertheless, good luck debugging!

Comment: Moved inline KV to separate file, called printcharacter as `sm.get_screen("character_sheet").printcharacter(statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)` and CharacterSheet as `        Label:
            text: root.myscb`

Other variables referenced as `self.myscb` etc. Many thanks to @EL3PHANTEN for his help.